# Return Inherited Class into Base Class WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am trying to return a derived class from the base class using WCF service, but I keep getting the following exception

`"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:50137/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server..."`

I have tried adding all of the following over WCF Service method.

1) `[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass1)), XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass2))]`

2) `[SoapRpcMethod]`

3) `[SoapInclude(typeof(DerivedClass1)), SoapInclude(typeof(DerivedClass2))]`

**Code:**

```
public class BaseClass
{
}
public class DerivedClass1:BaseClass
{
}
public class DerivedClass2:BaseClass
{
}
```

**Wcf Service Method:**

```
public BaseClass Validate()
{
    if(someCondition)
       return new DerivedClass1();
    else
       return new DerivedClass2();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[
   KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass1)), 
   KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass2))
]
public class BaseClass
{
}
public class DerivedClass1:BaseClass
{
}
public class DerivedClass2:BaseClass
{
}
```

see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx for more information about Known Types and the Generic Resolver.

Comment: You just saved my life!

Comment: Fabulous answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the code you've posted:

- Your contract type and operation code have no ServiceModel annotations
- You haven't specified how you're hosting the service
- You haven't specified how you're calling the service
- You haven't specified anything about the binding you're using

Until at least some of these are clarified I think the question is unanswerable. If you could edit your question to include these points I'll edit my answer.